# TheHive / Cortext - Adding observable in analyzer script

Tags: python, analyzer

In TheHive /Cortex I parse an observable, concretely an .eml file. The parser extract all ips and domains in it and save them in variables. Now I want to save these extracted ips and domains in new observables and add them to the active case. (for running other analyzers on them...)

Unfortenately I have no idea how to save observables out of an analyzer (.py) and I can't find any clues in the docu... any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you need implement the `artifacts` method to returns an array that defined those observables. you can use the `build_artifact` utility method from the `Analyzer` class.

Take a look at: https://github.com/TheHive-Project/Cortex-Analyzers/blob/master/analyzers/EmlParser/parse.py#L47